# Problemas con el paquete rae cuando la instalo con npm

Tags: nodejs, ubuntu, npm

Quiero instalar el paquete `rae` siguiendo las instrucciones de la página

https://www.npmjs.com/package/rae

Para instalar el paquete rae

```
$ npm install -g rae
```

Se instaló OK

```
 $ npm install -g rae
/home/user/.npm-global/bin/rae -> /home/user/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/rae/build/cli.js
+ rae@1.0.3
```

al verificar las versiones de ubuntu, node y npm da estos resultados:

```
$ lsb_release -a
```

Distributor ID: Ubuntu

Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS

Release:    20.04

Codename:   focal

```
 $ npm --version
```

8.4.0

```
 $ node --version
```

v12.22.9

El ejecutar el paquete rae

```
$ rae casa
```

Da este error:

```
(node:19439) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: e.log is not a function
    at h (/home/user/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/rae/build/cli.js:2:560278)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
(node:19439) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:19439) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

¿Alguna idea que pueda ser?